# Author of the post is not set to current logged in user

Tags: python, django

I created this simple model:

```
class FormModel(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I passed `blank=True` and `null=True` so that it can pass `form_valid` condition. and then set the  author of the current post to current logged in user, but sounds I am making a mistake here. Can anyone help. Here is how the views looks like:

```
def FormsView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormsProject(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.author = request.user.username
            print(form.author)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Success")
    else:
        form = FormsProject()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'user': request.user.username
    }
    return render(request, 'forms_project/forms.html', context)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the object coming from `form.save(...)`, then assign author value to it. Also, change from `request.user.username` to `request.user`, like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    modal = form.save(commit=False)
    modal.author = request.user
    modal.save()
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to store it back and why I can't pass `request.user.username`

Comment: because `author` is a FK field, hence it expects an object. `request.user.username` is a string, so `request.user` is the user object you need to assign.